# coolfieldset expand remove dispaly none of inside div

Tags: jquery

i am using this collapsible 
[Cool fieldset](http://stuff.w3shaman.com/jquery-plugins/coolfieldset/)

issue is that i have couple of fieldset

```
<fieldset id="fieldset1" class="coolfieldset">
    <legend>Default</legend>
    <div>
        <p>By default the <b>fieldset</b> is opened or expanded at start. Click on its <b>legend</b> to close or collapse it.</p>

        <p>The code is simply like below</p>

    </div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="fieldset2" class="coolfieldset">
    <legend>Default</legend>
    <div style="display:none">
        not visible
    </div>
</fieldset>

$('#fieldset1').coolfieldset({collapsed:true});
$('#fieldset2').coolfieldset();
```

now as soon as i close and open fieldset2 you can see my div which has style none opened which i dont want

can some one guide how can i stop that it do not remove the display none of my divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that the plugin you're using will always manipulate the divs inside the fieldset.

Having said that, I can think of two options for you:

**1** - use another element tag inside the fieldsets, for example:

```
<fieldset id="fieldset2" class="coolfieldset">
    <legend>Default</legend>
    <p style="display:none">
        Will not show.
    </p>
    <div style="display:none">
       will show
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

**2** - You could tweak the plugin itself (jquery.coolfieldset.js), so instead of targeting the divs inside the fieldset, you cuold use a class instead, it would be something like:

Change `obj.find('div')` to `obj.find('.myClass')`.
After that you could use it like this:

```
<fieldset id="fieldset2" class="coolfieldset">
        <legend>Default</legend>
        <div style="display:none">
            Will not show.
        </div>
        <div  class="myClass" style="display:none">
           will show
        </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: i am unable to find obj.find('div') in (jquery.coolfieldset.js), also i can not do the first option :(

Comment: just take a look at the code [here](http://stuff.w3shaman.com/jquery-plugins/coolfieldset/js/jquery.coolfieldset.js) it's quite straightforward...

Comment: http://w3shaman.com/article/jquery-plugin-collapsible-fieldset  in this page they ask to download from https://github.com/w3shaman/jquery-coolfieldset/blob/master/js/jquery.coolfieldset.js which is different from http://stuff.w3shaman.com/jquery-plugins/coolfieldset/js/jquery.coolfieldset.js

Comment: basically the same thing, but using JQuery's `:not()` Selector. Then just change `obj.children("*:not('legend')")` to `obj.children("*:not('legend, .myClass')")`. You can read more about the `:not()` Selector [here](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Comment: thanks it solve my issue , also i have marked this as answer :)